How can I capture the XYZ coordinates of an issue?
I am working with the Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC) API and I need to capture the XYZ coordinates of the created issues:
Issue
Could someone please provide guidance on how to capture the XYZ coordinates of the issues when creating them in ACC? Is there a specific method in the API to get this information?
We explored 199 tables accessible via Power BI when connecting to ACC. Unfortunately, none of these tables contained coordinate information. We did find tables related to markups, but these only contained GUIDs:
Markup Tables
could you tell me if these GUIDs are related to any table containing the XYZ coordinate information?
